# Set file modification time in java when effective ID doesn't match file

Tags: java

I have a java process which needs to update the modification time of a file which it doesn't own. I tried the program below which seemed to be correct but it fails with `Operation Not Permitted`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;

public class Touch {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (String filename : args) {
            try {
                Path path = new File(filename).toPath();
                FileTime time = FileTime.fromMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                Files.setLastModifiedTime(path, time);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Failed to touch: " + filename);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output of the program given an existing file `asdfasdf` owned by root, but I have write access to it via group (`0660` permissions).

```
$ strace -f -o mtime.log java -cp . Touch asdfasdf
Failed to touch: asdfasdf
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: asdfasdf: Operation not permitted
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.setTimes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:109)
        at java.nio.file.Files.setLastModifiedTime(Files.java:2306)
        at Touch.main(Touch.java:15)
```

The relevant portion of the strace is as follows:

```
13414 openat(AT_FDCWD, "asdfasdf", O_RDONLY) = 4
13414 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
13414 utimensat(4, NULL, [{tv_sec=1545468214, tv_nsec=0} /* 2018-12-22T03:43:34-0500 */, {tv_sec=1545470858, tv_nsec=462000000} /* 2018-12-22T04:27:38.462000000-0500 */], 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

`/usr/bin/touch` does what I want, so I strace'd that as well:

```
$ strace -f -o mtime.log touch asdfasdf
```

Here's the relevant portion of strace:

```
13483 openat(AT_FDCWD, "asdfasdf", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
13483 dup2(3, 0)                        = 0
13483 close(3)                          = 0
13483 utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)       = 0
```

Looking into the [utimensat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/utimensat) man page revealed that because java's calling with the `times` value `!= NULL`, the process must be the owner.

Is there a different way in the Java API which will call `utimensat()` with the correct arguments so I don't get the `EPERM`/`Operation Not Permitted` errors I'm seeing?

Further digging into `Files.setLastModifiedTime` for java 8 shows [UnixFileAttributeViews](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/a1ee9743f4ee/jdk/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileAttributeViews.java#l98) uses [futimes](https://linux.die.net/man/3/futimes) which then uses the previously found [utimensat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/utimensat) call.

Comment: Any interest the file is owned by root? May you use UnixFileAttributes yourself to work on permission?

Comment: I have permissions to write to the file via group permissions, so I'm allowed to update the modification time.